# LEDs driver circuit

Tags: led, oscillator, bjt

I was wondering what is the role of this type of circuit connected to LEDs.
I found it in a LED torch supplied by 2xAA batteries.
Is it an oscillator? Is it only an energy trick? What are the advantages of driving a LED with high frequencies?

(LEDs emit white light, BJT transistor NPN is 8122 or equivalent NTE108, the value of inductor is 10u about).

Thanks for replies

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn1rT4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is Q1 upside down?

Comment: I think Q1 must be upside down. I don't see at all how it would work with Q1 like that. But the catch is, I don't see how it would work the other way, either.

Comment: I'm doubtful indeed. The 8122 (or NTE108) transistor has TO92 package and my doubt is that on its datasheet (NTE108) the pinout is E-B-C (looked from the flat side), whereas others transistors (like BC547) has C-B-E pinout. However I drew the schematic considering the first case (NTE108 datasheet). If Q1 was upside down, it would have Vbe voltage of 3V, then it would work very beyond saturation.

Answer (score 3):

8122 is not a BJT, but a white led driver [YX8122](http://aitendo3.sakura.ne.jp/aitendo_data/product_img/ic/led_driver/YX/YX8122_aitendo.pdf)!

Answer (score 2):

This circuit is a variant of so called "[Joule Thief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief)" which is a variant of "[Blocking oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_oscillator)". The main use of it is to increase the battery voltage output, which is needed when the battery is considered to be "dead" by regular means.